# Can a certain piece of code be executed with a certain dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, json.net, .net-assembly

I have an issue where `Newtonsoft.Json` is loaded twice in my solution, with two different versions. This is because I am creating an Add-In in Revit, which loads by default version `9.0.0` of `Newtonsoft`.

The idea is that, when (de)serializing, the operation works well when I use version `11.0.0`, but doesn't if I use version `12.0.0` - which I actually want to use. Hence, the option of downgrading just to make the deserialization work is excluded for now.

What I am wondering is; is there any possibility that I could execute version `11.0.0` only on a certain portion of the code? For example, something like this:

```
execute Newtonsoft.Json.dll version 11.0.0
{
 var model = JsonConvert.Deserialize<ModelType>(json);
}
// the rest works with version 12.0.0
```

While the problem might not be this one, I am still curious if this is possible to achieve. Basically, I want a certain piece of code to be executed using a certain module, except for the one that is already referenced.

Comment: Any method in Net consists of the Namespace (like System.Collections.Generic), a Class, and a method.  When you use two difference libraries the Namespace is going to be different.  Normally you do not need to include the Namespace because the compiler will do a search for the the method/class in all the modules at the top of your code.  When there is a conflict and you have duplicate method names than you have to specify the full path of the method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @jdweng! I am not sure if I got this right - so the fact that there are two versions of Newtonsoft loaded, this means that it shouldn't have anything to do with my issues?

Comment: The versions are in the executable under different paths.  The source code could either use the one the compile finds without the full path (which may not be the correct version), or provide a full path to get the a specific version.

Comment: And is there any possibility that inside a certain method the code runs using the path to a specific version of that .dll?

Comment: A project has a list of references that contains all the libraries. The compiler looks at the using statements at the top of module to determine what libraries to use from the list of reference libraries.  The libraries should have different using statements at top of module or use a different namespace in the module.